# XCode 5 Interface Builder - How to remove the column separator in the header when there is only one column?

Tags: macos, tableview, xcode5

I'm hitting an annoying quirk in XCode 5.

I've created a Table View with Interface Builder & reduced the number of columns from 2 to 1. But I can't seem to get rid of the separator in the table header. i.e. I can use it to resize the column as if there are 2.

I've look through the IB options & opened the xml in the xib. But I cannot find any mention of a separator. I took a chance & removed the

```
<tableColumns>...</tableColumns>
```

tags and left just a single

```
<tableColumn>..</tableColumn>
```

entry but predictably that did not work.

The only way I've found to resolve this is to drag the separator off screen. Which seems iffy.

Are there any other options available?

[image: Hanging splitter]

Comment: Did you mean column or row? Also, I think a screenshot of the problem would help.

Comment: Updated. I meant column.